# Probability that 4 darts land on the same half of dartboard?

Tags: probability, statistics, conditional-probability

What is the probability that four darts (each thrown with an equal probability of hitting any point on the board) all land on the same half of the board?

Comment: Do first edit in what you have tried so far and where you are stuck.

Comment: It will depend on whether you split the board in two before or after you throw the darts

Comment: If you already split the board, for example into a left-half and a right-half, then this question is no different to asking what the probability is that when flipping four fair coins that they all land on the same face (all heads or all tails).  The second interpretation of that you can ask after all four darts are thrown if there exists some way to split the board in half (*presumably using a line that passes through the center*) such that all lie on one side of the line... that is a far more difficult question.